# Default value of Grocery CRUD datetime input?

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-ui-datepicker, grocery-crud

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794157/default-value-of-grocery-crud-date-input#_=_) is great! everything works fine with the datepicker.

But I have a problem with datetime-picker. as I see from another datetime field (without default value), the class used by that field defined as datetime-input.

So I tried to use :

```
$crud->set_js_config('assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.datetime.config.js');

...

<script type="text/javascript">var js_date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; </script>
<input name="date" type="text" value="'.date("d/m/Y H:i:s").'" class="datetime-input" />
<a class="datetime-input-clear ui-button " tabindex="-1" role="button">Clear</a>
```

even i've tried using class "timepicker" :

```
<input name="date" type="text" value="'.date("d/m/Y H:i:s").'" class="datetime-input timepicker" />
```

but the jquery datetime picker function is not available. Any idea how to make it works? Thank you

Comment: I cant understand your issue >> Are you looking for datetime picker field on add.. with default value or without ?

Comment: yes, I need a datetime picker field with default value. As I described at the second code, I want to show that field with value datetime "d/m/Y H:i:s". But, if I just use the code I wrote, the datetime picket not working, it won't show when i click the field.

Answer (score 0):

try to use callback field values.

```
$crud->callback_add_field('date_feild_name',array($this,'set_default_date'));

public function set_default_date(){
$value = date("d/m/Y");
$return = '<input id="field-date_feild_name" name="date_feild_name" type="text" value="'.$value.'" maxlength="10" class="datepicker-input hasDatepicker">
        <a class="datepicker-input-clear" tabindex="-1">Date feild name</a> (dd/mm/yyyy)';
return $return;
}
```